# Drawing HTML to a Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

With the advent of the new HTML5 Canvas, I was wondering if it's possible to draw a HTML section onto the canvas?

The idea is to take a piece of existing HTML code (from the same page, or defined elsewhere) and turn it into graphics.

Something like:

```
htContext.drawElement(document.getObjectByID("someObj"),0,0);
```

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. You need to get data from *drawed* element, or just for visual? On this case, use absolute position.

Comment: Do you need it to be cross-browser? A screen-taking plug-in might be a solution if not. In any case the rendering of the HTML is browser dependent - so you might get diff results in diff browsers.

Comment: It needs to work on Chrome(ium) browsers. I am a Delphi developer initially and need to embed a browser in my app to help a live designer. So i need some way of getting graphics from the browser into my "real" app. Since Chrome allows me to register javascript callbacks to my real app, I figured that if i could render graphics to a canvas - then i can save it as a png and deliver the data to my real app - thus saving months of work rendering it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox has proprietary method [drawWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow%28%29). With it you can draw the whole document on the canvas. But only in Firefox unfortunately. And also due to security issues you need permissions from the user to do it. So it's suitable only for some kind of internal project.

Here is the sample test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>drawWindow</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserRead');
            document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d').drawWindow(window, 0, 0, 100, 200, "rgb(255,255,255)");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not only the windows, drawWindow can take a DOM subset in parameter.

Comment: That was pretty much what i was after. So this is 100% firefox only? Is it possible to something similar under webkit? It is an internal project so i dont have to worry about security.

Comment: Just realized that this is for GUI extensions only, which is not what i need :( I need to view a html page, then get the page as a bitmap or image into my app. Surely there must be some solution for this?

Comment: WOW! That is absolutely fantastic! Cant wait to try it out. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Didnt work under chrome as you said :( Have to find a better wrapper or wait until it's added to chromium

Comment: Note that `drawWindow` is now available only to code running with chrome-permissions (so the UI and extensions, essentially) and not general webpage content, now that `UniversalBrowserRead` is gone and I think `enablePrivilege` is too (or will soon be).