# javascript bitmap data composite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found [this library(BitmapData.js)](https://github.com/pnitsch/BitmapData.js) that can make composites of images as bitmap data. 
However it can only composite image objects. 
Does anyone know how to composite `Images` with other `DOM` elements such as a div that contains text and output the 2 layers as a flattened bitmap data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing HTML to a Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098213/drawing-html-to-a-canvas)

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the link, however when i tried html2canvas it gave a screenshot of the dom and was not a bitmap of the elements. In other words i could not scale the output without distortion

Comment: Afaik, with html2canvas you need to scale the input, i.e. the elements before taking the "screenshot"

Comment: @Bergi i see what you mean.  let me try moving the "shot" off of the visible area and screen shoot that, maybe that will do it.